# What's the highest price a country charges citizens of another country for tourist visa?

Tags: visas, budget, factoids, countries, australian-citizens

Many countries charge money to issue visas to people wishing to enter, and many charge different fees for citizens of different countries.

On my current trip the most I've had to pay was $20. One other country I thought about visiting would've cost $100. And I've heard other travellers talking about some visas costing around $300.

**I've been wondering which country charges the most for a normal tourist visa to citizens of which other country.**

As a bonus question I'm also wondering which country charges the most for a citizen of Australia to visit.

To be clear, I am only interested in tourist visas for whatever duration - not other kinds of visas. I am specifically not asking about any other costs that a person applying for the visa might also have to pay.

Comment: I'm assuming this is non-urgent shortest-term single-entry tourist visas?

Comment: Tourist visa from Middle east to USA costs around $233 minimum, sometimes they ask for more depending on a creteria i am not aware of.

Comment: And what about when a country insists on an invitation as well? Oh wait, just saw, you exclude that. Rules out compulsory tours to North Korea too.

Comment: @MarkMayo: I used the word "normal" with tourist visa, but when I did I also realized I didn't know what kind of variations might exist. But yeah definitely not including any other costs that might be compulsory but not the actual visa price itself. I thought that would make the question too open ended.

Comment: I have already mentioned [cost of staying in Bhutan](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5810/241) as a tourist ($200 per day), but this does not concern specifically visa.

Answer (score 7):

Since last year's unpleasantness, Bahrain has hiked [its visa fees](http://www.mofa.gov.bh/Default.aspx?tabid=7617) way, way up:

> USA, Canada and UK visa fee: $228.00
>
> For all others, visa fee: $270.00 (Applicants from 35 countries)

However, this is only for long-term tourist visas over 2 weeks.  Most nationalities can still obtain two-week visas on arrival and advance e-visas for a [considerably more reasonable BD 7](http://www.evisa.gov.bh/VisaBhr3En.html), or around US$19.

---

Another good candidate is the Democratic Republic of the Congo, where tourist visas issued at the Rwandan border cost a [cool US$285](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/tonywheeler/my_lists/congo_information/).  However, advance single entry visas are again more reasonable at GBP 60.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a study by Airport Parking and Hotels](http://www.scotsman.com/the-scotsman/personal-finance/russian-visas-are-the-most-expensive-in-the-world-1-2111162) (APH) - (yeah I wouldn't trust that source either, but at least it's published), Russia is the most expensive visa to achieve.

Note that this is for UK nationals, but it's a start.

> The former Soviet country charges £115 for a standard entry visa, with
>   costs soaring as high as £220 for an “express” service.
>
> Tanzania and Vietnam are the next most expensive travel destinations
>   in terms of visas – charging £38 each for a single entry visa,
>   according to Airport Parking and Hotels (APH), the long stay airport
>   parking specialist – followed by China and India at £30.

Annoyingly they only surveyed 18 countries, and I'd love to know what they get for Bahrain, Argentina or Angola, who I've heard are expensive for Brits...

Answer (score 3):

US charges between $150 and >$500, depending on the visa type, and the country of origin. And that's just for the interview. In return, some countries (in Latin America, for example) charge US citizens similar amounts. I know that Russia used to charge some obscene amounts (~$150) for a single entry visa a decade or so ago, don't know if its still the case.

Also, the costs should be adjusted to the length of the visa validity. Paying $150 for a 10-years multiple entry B1/B2 (tourist) US visa shouldn't be compared as similar as paying $150 for a 6-months single entry visitor visa to Russia.

And last but not least... The US for example charges hundreds of dollars from citizens of certain countries for limited visas, while allowing WVP (visa-free) travel to citizens of others. So many Europeans are not aware at all of the US visa charges, while many Middle-Eastern, Chinese and Indians need to empty their pockets.

(not to bash the US, I live there, just an example of how it is difficult to answer the question asked).

Comment: I'm not sure the charge for the visa interview is the charge for the visa itself, but I expected there would be grey areas...

Comment: Also you never know, we might find out that some other country charges much more than $150 for a 10-year multiple entry visa...

Comment: @hippietrail I believe that the "interview" fee is officially describes as the application fee, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

North Korea?

In order to go, you have to go on the government tour, which is about €1,000 IIRC. (It's not technically a "visa" but if you don't pay it, you can't get in)

Comment: I was pretty specific about only asking about the actual visa fee. We could get into all sorts of stuff like how much travel insurance might cost to cover health care in the USA etc etc.

Comment: Oh yes I suppose. But "health insurance" is not required to enter the USA, only a "nice to have".

Comment: This is similar to [the comment above about the cost of staying in Bhutan as a tourist](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7325/whats-the-highest-price-a-country-charges-citizens-of-another-country-for-touri#comment9593_7325). While compulsory costs, they are not the visa costs.