# How to tell if your flight has an air-bridge or stairs?

Tags: air-travel, airports, accessibility, airport-terminals

A colleague has a family member who struggles with the stairs, and wouldn't be able to climb (injury).   They've spotted a trip to Tasmania on Jetstar from Sydney, but are wondering if the planes have stairs or an [air-bridge/jet-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bridge).

The flights are JQ747 and JQ748, but I'd prefer a more generic way of finding out this information?

Comment: @pnuts I guess they'd like some certainty, but if it changed it looks like the airline has lifts for the planes for disabled passengers, but they'd prefer to not use these services.

Comment: If you contact the airline in advance and advise them of the situation, they may be able to secure [a special lift](https://www.ana.co.jp/cont-image/unique/right/3466-lang-multi.jpg) if the aircraft is to be boarded by stairs. This is especially common in the US, where there are comparatively strong legal protections for people with disabilities, but it's worth inquiring anywhere.

Comment: @ZachLipton yes, as said in previous comment the airline does have that option, but ideally they'd like to know in advance if they would need it.

Comment: And I figured there *must* be a way to look this stuff up.

Comment: Yep I didn't see your comment before I posted, as they were near simultaneous I guess.

Comment: This is something you should advise the airline of as soon as possible, ideally right after booking the flight, so that they can make the necessary arrangements.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep, Jetstar has that option at booking time online to specify.  I was just trying to find out how to tell.

Comment: Not sure but I would look at the airport first. Plenty simply don't have jet-bridges.

Comment: Related (but opposite) question:  http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10326/4171

Comment: @AriBrodsky hah, we joked about that very idea at work today. That's cool!

Comment: @ZachLipton: same in the EU

Comment: Some (or many) airports do have bridges but still do 'walk to the plane and up the stairs' like Schiphol for most Easyjet planes, as well as several 'bus to plane and walk up the stairs'.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Flights JQ747/JQ748 are to/from **Launceston Airport**, [which does not have aerobridges](https://airports.asn.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/resources/Disability%20Access%20Facilitation%20Plan%20-%20Launceston%20Airport%20-%202013.pdf):

> Due to airport operating restrictions, Launceston airport cannot provide aerobridges to board aircraft.  All access onto the aircraft is via aircraft stairs or mechanical lifting equipment (Disabled Person Lift) operated by the airlines. airline staff
> will provide the assistance required to board the aircraft in an appropriate manner.

I would strongly advise you to contact the airline and notify them that you will likely need assistance, and arrive early for check in so you can ensure they're ready.

On the Sydney side, Jetstar flights typically do use aerobridges, but these are some bus-only gates as well.  The airline will be able to advise you regarding this as well.

As for a generic way to find out, I suppose you could always look at the airport in [the satellite view on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/oKhmPSKJTut), but even if the airport *has* gates does not guarantee that your flight will use them.  So, again, contacting the airline is by far your best bet.

Comment: It sounds like the best solution here would be for your colleague or their family member to contact the airline in advance and make sure that they will be able to accommodate them. Even if they have lifting equipment, they may still require advance notice so they can make sure one will be available and have it in the appropriate place.

Comment: Even if the airport had bridges (such as Heathrow) there is no guarantee it will be used.

Comment: This problem falls under disability and it is usually the airport that facilitates with this NOT the airline. So you need to contact the airport on both sides probably and request "wheel chair access".  They use lifts and other routes to get you on board. But you need to genuinely provide disability papers.

Comment: I have never heard of being asked for papers RE disabilities. Whenever we have travelled with my grandmother, we have just asked (in advance). For many airlines (and I believe all of the ones in the EU) there are options available during ticket purchase and/or online check in to indicate that assistance will be required. The options aren't always that visible though.

Comment: To confirm the need to inform the airline and arrange assistance even if the airport has air-bridge gates: I recently had to climb stairs onto a 747 for a flight from London Heathrow, which has many air-bridge gates. I have taken the same flight, BA273, several times in the past and it was always a bridge.

Answer (score 38):

There is no way to guarantee either. Aircraft parking assignments are planned in advance, but subject to change without prior notice due to various reasons, such as the previous flight using the gate being delayed.

You can decrease the risk of a bus gate (stairs) by choosing flights that come and go during the daytime, early evening, as they do their best to park turn around flights at the gate for more efficient loading and unloading.  Flights that arrive late or depart very early may use aircraft that park overnight, which would be more likely to use a bus gate to keep jet bridges open for turn arounds.

But if the flight uses a bus gate or stairs, then all airlines and airports have means to board passengers with mobility issues, ranging from simply carrying a specially designed wheelchair up the stairs, to using a lift truck to move the passenger and wheelchair up to one of the service doors.

Comment: In my experience, many such passengers prefer not to be carried if possible, or at least would like to know what the arrangements are in advance. Asking is the best way to find out though; many airlines have a special number or department to address disability requests.

Comment: well said on the last. I've seen it done on rare occasions.

Comment: FWIW, "bus gates" and "stairs" are two orthogonal issues. I've seen bridges with stairs and bus gates without…

Comment: Well, there is _one_ way to get at least pretty close to being sure whether you'll use a boarding bridge: book a flight on an airline that either always or never uses them at the airports on your itinerary. Of course, there's still the outside possibility of a diversion to another airport or some irregular operations issue causing that to change, but it's about as good as you can do.

Comment: @reirab: Even then, you can be surprised.  JAL went through a period a few years ago when their evening flight from Narita to Bangkok parked away from the terminal building and used stairs on arrival.  I actually found myself enjoying it, even though stairs give me some difficulty: you don't really appreciate how BIG a 747 or 777 is until you're standing ON THE GROUND next to one, and realizing you're looking something easily three to four stories tall (and that's NOT including the vertical tail!).

Comment: Perhaps all the down voters can add a comment explaining their displeasure with this answer?

Comment: @user13044 that sadly almost never happens :/

Answer (score 15):

It is not the flight/plane themselves that could be the problem, but the airport.

If your friend's family member needs extra help to board the plane, then they should ask the airport/airline directly for assistance. (As soon as possible)

For example, 
I assume they will go to Launceston airport in Tasmania.

They have a "disability/accessibility plan" that supports different disability (wheelchairs and other )

https://www.launcestonairport.com.au/accessibility

I assume Sydney Airport has the same kind of assistance.

Either jet-bridges if boarding from the airport, or ramps (or elevators) if boarding from the tarmac.

Comment: Yeah, the airline (Jetstar) provides this service free, but they're wondering how to find out in advance if a particular flight will need one (obviously it depends on the airport)

Comment: Hi Max! The link here is dead, but it does lead to the same company's website. They do have a [disability plan](https://www.launcestonairport.com.au/corporate-news/2016/launceston-airport-updates-disability-access-facilitation-plan) but that has a dead link too! They also have an [Access Plan](https://www.launcestonairport.com.au/accessibility) on their site, but it's not a pdf. I wanted to try to replace the link for you, but don't think I accurately can! If you have a minute and want to change the link, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sue, updated.the link

Answer (score 9):

As far as I am aware there is no generic way to discover this information. See the discussion at 
[Ryanair Using Jetbridges, Where?](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=537995) about this topic where a Ryanair crewmember was unsure whether they use it at BUD or not as it was not his/her route and also someone pointed out sometimes it's just "depends" and that easyJet some places uses *both*.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to address your need rather than answer your question directly:

- Visit the airport's website.
- Figure out the best **telephone number** to call regarding service for **passengers with disabilities/special needs** (it might just be some single center service number of course).
- **Call and tell them** about your friend's physical trouble, and ask them how can it be arranged for him not to be inconvenienced/suffer any pain.
- Suggest options such as: Ensuring an air-bridge; offering to take him out via an elevator down to the tarmac, then using a mobile lifter to the airplane's entrance; or whatever arrangement they suggest that I might not have though of (ramps? being carried on a chair?).

I'd say that's the best you can do in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

If the airport is small it may not have bridges and thus you know it will be stairs.  Otherwise you can't know as it can be situational:  "They don't have a gate for us, we are going to use stairs."  It's happened to me twice at major (admittedly foreign) airports.

And since I wrote this I've had to use stairs twice at major US airports.  Seattle has some "gates" that are always actually stairs.