# Can travellers see Buddhist temples in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: sightseeing, religion, architecture, saudi-arabia

Can travellers see Buddhist temples in Saudi Arabia?

I'm not a Buddhist myself, but I sometimes see Buddhist temples when travelling. Wikipedia mentions that there's approximately [400,000 Buddhists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Saudi_Arabia) in Saudi Arabia. Are there any Buddhist temples, whose existence is publicly known, that I can see?

Comment: there's no non-Muslim religious places in Saudi Arabia as there's no religious freedom there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion_in_Saudi_Arabia, [Why are worshiping places of other religions (Church, Temple) prohibited in Saudi Arabia?](http://islam.stackfaq.net/q/2883), [Why is it that in Saudi Arabia, there are no churches nor any temples? Why do they punish people for having their private prayers?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-in-Saudi-Arabia-there-are-no-churches-nor-any-temples-Why-do-they-punish-people-for-having-their-private-prayers)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_in_Saudi_Arabia [What are the options to travel to Mecca or Jabal al-Nour as a non-Muslim?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56611/13777)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc the "Why are worshiping places of other religions (Church, Temple) prohibited in Saudi Arabia?" link is to a copycat site (stackfaq net) rather than Stack Exchange. I'm worried it may have malware on the site.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are no such temples in Saudi Arabia - source: 26+ years of living there.

There are way more Christians in Saudi Arabia than Buddhists - but there are no churches in Saudi Arabia either.

It is enshrined in the law - which states that all people are free to practice their religion in private only. Public houses of worship for other religions are not allowed.

The Committee for the Promotion of Virtue and the Prevention of Vice - known by their Arabic: مطوعين‎, enforces this prohibition.

Comment: Actually it's "مطاوعة" in the local dialect, an irregular plural.

Comment: I always thought "مطاوعة" was the singular form and مطوعين the name of the agency; but I'm not a native speaker of Arabic. No confusion as to what they look like though ;-)

Comment: The agency is called "الهيئة" for short, "مطوع" is the singular form. They look alike anyway and they all have the same mentality, so singular or plural makes no difference...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, Saudi Arabia is a muslim country and it has been for the last 1400 years or so, and all the Buddhist are foreigners that work in SA and not native to the country, so no there isn't any Buddhist temples at all. ( I am sure that  the  sudi government wont allow any to be built ).

Comment: The problem is not that Saudi Arabia is a Muslim country— so is Indonesia, and you can find Buddhist temples there. The problem is that the Saudi government does not allow public worship of any non-Islamic religions, owing in turn to its historical relationship with one particular interpretation of Islam.

Comment: @choster is right, you can find several Buddhist temples in Iran (Muslim country) either

Comment: In addition to Iran and Indonesia, there are non-Muslim worship facilities in Egypt, Turkey, Morocco, Iraq, and Malaysia. Completely banning public non-Muslim worship is not the standard practice in most Muslim countries.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, and Oman.