# Are there any areas in Mecca that non-Muslims are allowed to enter under Saudi Arabian law?

Tags: regulations, saudi-arabia, islam, mecca

I know Mecca is one of the most sacred sites in Islam and that a merchant was kicked out [for entering the site and being Christian](http://www.jpost.com/International/Saudis-arrest-Christian-for-entering-Mecca) and that non-Muslims who enter the [most sacred regions of the city could be kicked out of Saudi Arabia](http://www.vox.com/2016/9/12/12814258/hajj-islamic-pilgrimage-mecca-explained).

However, are there any places in the city of Mecca that non-Muslims are allowed to visit without breaking the law?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mecca (or Makkah as pronounced in Arabic) is a region in Saudi Arabia, one of its cities is [Mecca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecca) (clearly, the same name as the region's name). Other cities include [Jeddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeddah) and [Taif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taif), which anyone can visit.

So, if you mean the city, then the answer is mostly **No**, if you mean the region, then the answer is **Yes**.

Going back to the city, according to Islam (as some interpret it), only the sacred area (the [mosque area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mosque_of_Mecca) and the surroundings, other sacred areas like Arafah And Mina, etc.) is not allowed for non-Muslims. However, that is quite hard to apply due to Mecca being in the mountains area, so the ban is extended to cover almost all Mecca (it's not a large city anyway). There are road signs that show the Muslims-Only areas.

[image: road sign]
The photo is from Google. ([Here](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e5d9cd6c568846725c7aa92d97afe3d5.webp) is a link to one version on internet.)

Comment: And old related answer here: [https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56611/what-are-the-options-to-travel-to-mecca-or-jabal-al-nour-as-a-non-muslim]

Comment: It is a remarkable road sign.  I wonder whether there are any others like it.  It is tempting to post a question.

Comment: Did you take the photo yourself?  If not, could you please add proper attribution?

Comment: I don't think "from Google" is [proper attribution](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  Who actually created the photo?  How do you know you have permission to use it here?

Comment: I doubt the picture is from Google *itself*.  I mean what did you think? That Google has a fleet of cars driving all over the world taking pictures of roads or something... what are the chances of that, right? ;)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I stole it. Is that what you all want to hear.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Nah you're cool... I'm making a joke.  Actually Google *does* have a fleet of cars driving all over the world taking pictures of roads.  It's called Google Street View :) So saying "it's from Google" is perfectly plausible.  (and you can hit "delete" on comments btw)

Comment: A look at Street View reveals almost no Google-sourced imagery from Saudi Arabia.

Comment: How do they enforce these rules for foreigners? Maybe residents have a religion on their ID cards (Iran does this for instance), but how can they tell whether someone from another country is Muslim or not, given that people of every ethnicity and background perform hajj?

Comment: Are the boundaries marked?