# Can a Muslim woman visit Medina Mosques as tourist independently?

Tags: visas, solo-travel, saudi-arabia, female-travellers, mosques

I’m a Muslim girl from Romania. How can I get a visa to visit the Prophet’s Mosque in Medina, Saudi Arabia?

Answer (score 20):

**Sorry, you can't**. Women under 45 are not granted pilgrimage visas unless they travel with a male guardian, and even if you're over 45, you need to travel with a group.  [Royal Embassy of Saudi Arabia to the US](http://www.saudiembassy.net/services/hajj_requirements.aspx):

> 4) All women are required to travel for Hajj with a Mahram [*male guardian*, see [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram). Proof of
>   kinship must be submitted with the application form. Women over the
>   age of forty-five (45) may travel without a Mahram with an organized
>   group, They must, however submits a no objection letter from her
>   husband, son or brother authorizing her to travel for Hajj with the
>   named group. This letter should be notarized.

See also: [How to independently visit Saudi Arabia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/how-to-independently-visit-saudi-arabia)

Comment: How is about boys?

Comment: Minors are not granted visas unless travelling with their guardians, see point 10: http://www.saudiembassy.net/services/hajj_requirements.aspx

Comment: Ok, but what about if I know a friend (male) there in Madina, he could be my Mahram?

Comment: No, only your relatives can be your *mahram*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram