# Traveler's Century Club: Something similar just for Europe?

Tags: europe, countries, socializing

Yesterday I heard for the first time about the [Traveler's Century Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelers%27_Century_Club).

To become a member of this club you have to visit 100 or more countries. Although I'm not really interested in joining such a club, I'm curious if there is a similar club for European countries. So let's say you can become a member if you have visited 80% of all European countries.

I couldn't find something like this.

Comment: it is just too easy to visit all European countries, still I haven't done that.

Comment: Yes that's true. I have still to visit some of them. Particularly in Southeast Europe.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3198/101

Comment: It might be easy to visit every country. But it could be more challenging to visit every region/province, or every city over a certain size ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had a lot of looking at sites like this (Traveller Century Club, Most Traveled People, etc), and while there's a US Centric one (The All Fifty States Club), I've never seen a European one.  Perhaps it's time to start one? :)

Of course, the biggest problem you'll have is - what counts as a visit?  [This blog post](http://countycounting.blogspot.co.nz/) has a great description of the argument faced - is it when you set foot? Leave the airport? Eat a meal? Sleep one light?  What counts as visiting?

Then you have the problem of what IS a country?  Is Gibraltar? What about Kosovo?

There's also an Extra Milers Club - which records visits to all 3142 counties of The US :)

Comment: Good points. I personally count a visit when I set a foot on it, but not on the airport area. An a country is a country if it is or was recognized by the UN.

Comment: So what about these ones then? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_limited_recognition#Non-UN_member_states_recognised_by_at_least_one_UN_member :)  I certainly count QwaQwa from my travels - it no longer exists, but South Africa used to recognise it and as its only neighbour, that seemed good enough to me.

Comment: Yes starting one would be a cool thing.

Comment: just have to think what would be a fair number of European countries... maybe 45

Comment: Well when you're starting your own club, **you** get to make up all the rules and definitions. So I would like to propose, in our grand tradition here at Travel.SE, that it counts only if you had to go to the toilet.